# WPF CustomControl can't inherit from TextBlock control

Tags: wpf

I'm making a WPF CustomControlLibrary with CustomControls which inherit from standard controls like Label, TextBox etc.
When i try to make another CustomControl which inherit from TextBlock, i get strange errors.
It seems to be that a CustomControl can't inherit from the TextBlock.

But why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any detail on the "strange errors" might help?

Comment: In my case the CustomControl which inherits from TextBlock cannot be registered anymore and is not known either to the library-project and to the WPF-Project which has a reference to the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just created custom control inherited from TextBlock:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class CustomTextBlock : TextBlock
    {
    }
}
```

and used it within the same project:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Grid>
        <local:CustomTextBlock Text="Hello" />
    </Grid>        
</Window>
```

So the anser is:

### you can inherit from TextBlock

however, in order t use it in xaml, you have to compile the project first. There may be other errors in your code that prevents the project to compile and therefore you may be getting also errors like

`The type 'local:CustomTextBlock' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built`

or simmilar error:

`The name "CustomTextBlock" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication1".`

Once you fix the other errors, these will disappear as well.

Comment: I tried it, but now i get another error message in my Generic.xaml: The style property "Template" was not found in type "CustomTextBlock".

Comment: It's because TextBlock does not have a template. You can't specify a template for a control that does not have a template. You are probably looking for ContentControl, not a TextBlock. And if you want just change appearance and don't need to specify any extra properties, than you don't need custom control at all. All you need is to create separate style for ContentControl or a Label

Comment: Okay Liero, that's what i thought too after Your answer. thanks a lot!